# installing svnbridge server on a different machine other than the server

Tags: svnbridge

I can see that there is a key called "TfsUrl" in the appSettings part of the Web.config file for SVNBridge. Is this possible? Can I install the SVNBridge on a different machine to the TFS server? We are a big company and the admin people don't want to install svnbridge on their server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. However, I have found it to be very slow depending on where the SVNBridge server is. In my testing I installed the SVNBridge server locally and pointed it at my production server over a VPN. With this setup it would take up to 3 minutes to just open the repository in TortoiseSVN. With the SVNBrige server installed on the same machine as TFS the load time is almost unnoticeable.